# Display stock_status_id in view in Opencart

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller, opencart

I've found the stock status id product model, but have no idea, how to pass it to view or controller

Answer (score 0):

added the following code to controller of product

```html
$data['stock_status_id'] = $product_info['stock_status_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different code for different version in opencart

> For oc1531 to oc1564 version,

Controller:

```
$this->data['stock_status_id'] = $product_info['stock_status_id'];
```

View:

```
<?php echo $stock_status_id; ?>
```

> For oc2.x version

Controller:

```
$data['stock_status_id'] = $product_info['stock_status_id'];
```

View:

```
<?php echo $stock_status_id; ?>
```

> For oc3.x version

Controller:

```
$data['stock_status_id'] = $product_info['stock_status_id'];
```

View:

```
{{ stock_status_id }}
```